# How to block the merge of Current PR if the previous CI build is failed and it should pass the PR if the previous build is successful?

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops

I have two branches of master & dev in Azure Repo ....if i made a PR from dev to master...if the previous CI build is successful then it should allow to merge...in case if the previous build is failed then the merge should be blocked

Answer (score 0):

The branch policies contains [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) rule as workaround. You create PR and its changes will be built with pipeline. If build failed, PR will not be completed:

[image]

So you can not get broken code in your master branch.

Comment: i added the Branch Policy with build validation....but it still allowing to merge PR when the previous build is failed..!

Comment: @VigneshArvind That is interesting. I have checked on my test project and add image into the answer as result: I can not complete PR if build failed. Check **Required** option in **Policy requirement** section of your branch policy.